# Does multiplying a transformation matrix by a scalar change the transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I'm solving some exercises that I found online relating to transformation matrices and change of basis matrices. I'm having trouble understanding the last part of the answer.

Here's the question:

Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}5&-3\\2&-2\end{bmatrix}$, which is a linear transformation $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$. Find the matrix  representing the transformation with respect to basis B = $\begin{bmatrix}3&1\\1&2\end{bmatrix}$.

I understand how to solve the question. You would do $B^{-1}AB$. I did the multiplication and got $\begin{bmatrix}20&0\\0&-5\end{bmatrix}$. The author of the document got the same answer but then multiplied the matrix by 1/5 to get $\begin{bmatrix}4&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$. Why is he allowed to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a mistake:  $1/5$ is included into $B^{-1}$, which you forgot.

Comment: You're right! Thanks